# searching bin number in netsuite using C# code

Tags: c#, netsuite

I am trying to search a bin number = "1" from given location (warehouse). My code is like

```
        RecordRef[] referLocation = new RecordRef[1] { new RecordRef { } };
        referLocation[0].type = RecordType.location;
        referLocation[0].internalId = "6";

        BinSearch bSearch = new BinSearch();
        BinSearchBasic bSBasic = new BinSearchBasic();
        SearchStringField strField = new SearchStringField ();
        SearchMultiSelectField multiSelect = new SearchMultiSelectField();

        multiSelect.searchValue = referLocation;
        bSBasic.location = multiSelect;
        strField.searchValue = "1";
        bSBasic.binNumber = strField;
        bSearch.basic = bSBasic;

        var response = _service.search(bSearch);
        if (response.status.isSuccess)
            Console.WriteLine(strField.searchValue + "exists");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(strField.searchValue + "Not exists");
```

But even if the bin number = 1 is in te netsuite, it is giving Not Exists. Can anybody help me to point out what wrong or missing in the code? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found is that if a record is marked as "Inactive" in NetSuite, it will not be returned in any API searches, and any add/update calls which pass that ID will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided operator in any of the search criteria, add these lines to your code before passing the search values in basic search:

```
multiSelect.@operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
multiSelect.operatorSpecified = true;

strField.@operator = SearchStringFieldOperator.@is;
strField.operatorSpecified = true;
```